# How to pass parameter to the view corresponding store?

Tags: extjs

I have view like :

```
Ext.define('Example.demo..Structure', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    xtype: 'structure',

   height:700,
   title: 'Files',
   rootVisible: false,
   layout :{
       type: 'vbox',
       pack: 'start',
       align: 'stretch'
   },
   initComponent: function() {
       var tempName = this.param;
       Ext.apply(this, {

           store:  new Ext.data.TreeStore({
               model: Example.demo.Structure,
               proxy: {
               type: 'ajax',
               url: 'data/main/content/source/folder/' + tempName,
               method:'GET'
           },
           folderSort: true
       }),
       columns: [{
           xtype: 'treecolumn', //this is so we know which column will show the tree
           text: 'Files',
           flex: 2,
           sortable: true,
           dataIndex: 'name'
       }]
               });
               this.callParent();
           }
});
```

Here, I am creating the store and adding parameter in the url.

I want store to be in other location and I should pass the tempName variable to that store file and just include that store here in the view.

How should I do it?

Comment: I think you can do it like...1.Place the store in separate file 2.Add the file in the above file using requires 3.Use store lookup to get that store and configure the proxy as you required,and then load the store.

Comment: How to use store lookup if u can suggest through small code snippet. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I do so:

1. declare a tree without store
2. declare a store without proxy.url
3. at the right time doing so:

   ```
   store.proxy.url = 'data/main/content/source/folder/' + tempName;
       store.load(
               {
                   callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                       if (success) {
                           tree.reconfigure(store);
                       } 
                   }
               }
       );
   ```